# Error in creating lxc container on Ubuntu 16.0.4LTS 32bit

Tags: 16.04, lxc

I am running Ubuntu 32-bit 16.0.4.

```
> cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial

> uname -a
Linux manik 4.4.0-36-generic #55 SMP Tue Sep 13 15:51:05 PDT 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

I installed `lxc` package via the followng :

```
sudo apt-get install lxc
```

After that, I created a config file for `unprivileged container` in `~/.config/lxc/default.conf` as:

```
lxc.id_map = u 0 100000 65536
lxc.id_map = g 0 100000 65536
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.link = lxcbr0
```

I tried to create unprivileged container but got errors:

```
lxc-create -t download -n game_container -l DEBUG -o /tmp/lxc-create -- --no-validate -d ubuntu -r xenial -a i386
Downloading the image index
ERROR: Failed to download http://images.linuxcontainers.org//meta/1.0/index-user
lxc-create: lxccontainer.c: create_run_template: 1290 container creation template for game_container failed
lxc-create: tools/lxc_create.c: main: 318 Error creating container game_container
```

I looked at the log file `/tmp/lxc-create` and it had the following entries:

```
     lxc-create 20160914131038.765 INFO     lxc_confile - confile.c:config_idmap:1500 - read uid map: type u nsid 0 hostid 100000 range 65536
     lxc-create 20160914131038.765 INFO     lxc_confile - confile.c:config_idmap:1500 - read uid map: type g nsid 0 hostid 100000 range 65536
     lxc-create 20160914131038.876 INFO     lxc_confile - confile.c:config_idmap:1500 - read uid map: type u nsid 0 hostid 100000 range 65536
     lxc-create 20160914131038.876 INFO     lxc_confile - confile.c:config_idmap:1500 - read uid map: type g nsid 0 hostid 100000 range 65536
     lxc-create 20160914131052.728 ERROR    lxc_container - lxccontainer.c:create_run_template:1290 - container creation template for game_container failed
     lxc-create 20160914131052.732 INFO     lxc_container - lxccontainer.c:container_destroy:2387 - Destroyed rootfs for game_container
     lxc-create 20160914131052.735 INFO     lxc_container - lxccontainer.c:container_destroy:2403 - Destroyed directory for game_container
     lxc-create 20160914131052.735 ERROR    lxc_create_ui - tools/lxc_create.c:main:318 - Error creating container game_container
```

Any idea what is happening here ? Is there anything I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue. The problem was with the `openssl` installation on my distribution. 
Few days back, I was messing around with openssl and its ca certificates. that seem to have messed up my system-wide openssl. 
I reinstalled the openssl and everything worked fine.

It was little work to find out the cause though. the `lxc-download` template script does not throw any informative errors, so I had to look around a bit. And eventually found out that the ca certificate verification was failing.